# Apache on host requires password but won't accept user credentials

Tags: apache, ubuntu, server

Hi i have set up a virtual machine with ubuntu server 16.04 and i have installed virtualbox-guest utilities as well and i am now busy setting up my apache server but when i try to access my apache server status page from my host machine by using http://my_domain_name:8080 i get the following prompt "Your connection to this site is not private" and prompts met to enter a username and password.

I have tried all my user names and password that i can think of but it will not accept my admin credentials or my local credentials.

Which password should i enter here and where can i find these details? I followed the following youtube video to assist me in setting up the machine. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dJwSgypywB4&t=784s. (Part 2 of the video)

Comment: - Are you sure, you see this message "Your connection to this site is not private" when used with HTTP Protocol and 8080 port ? What is the error seen in the logs ?

Comment: I found my error my Oracle database on my host was clashing with my guest database. I removed that one and it is working now